# What is the difference between stl_list.h and list.h?

Tags: c++, list, stl

In my project,I use `#include <list>`,then I found that `list` linked to 'list.h'.
But in other peoples' project,I found that 'list' linked to 'stl_list.h', and I coundnt find where he includes it.
What is the difference between stl_list.h and list.h?
Are they used in the same way?

Comment: `stl_list.h` is an implementation detail and should not be used.

Comment: Before C++ was standardized in 1998, the "standard" container like `vector` and `list` were usually defined in header files like `<vector.h>` and `<list.h>`. The standard defined that all standard library header files should be without the `.h` suffix, so they now were named `<vector>` and `<list>`. Furthermore, parts of the standard library came from [the STL (Standard Template Library)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) which is *not* the same as the C++ standard library. If you include `<list.h>` or `<stl_list.h>` you're not using the standard C++ `std::list`.